# How to use stash when render file in command (mojolicious)

Tags: templates, render, mojolicious

I render file in command using Mojo::Template. How can I use stash (like in controller `$c->stash(value => 1)`). I know I be able pass array. But I need use the stash.

`my $mt = Mojo::Template->new; my $html =  $mt->render_file( 'templates/some_file.html.ep', %$options );`
It`s wrong data format for options. How to do it right?
Or maybe it is passible to use 'render_to_string' in command? Sanks

Answer (score 1):

```
my $c = $app->build_controller;
$c->( 'templates/some_file.html.ep', %$options );
```